# Controls blue by default? Visual Basic 2010 Express

Tags: vb.net, styles, controls

Recently I have downloaded VB 2010 Express to try and get back into VB programming. However, for some reason, all the controls I make are blue and look like the ones in the actual program. How do I change this? I searched everywhere...

And also, yes I know - off topic. I apologise. But I didn't know where else to put it...

Thank you,
UL

Comment: Can you post a picture of your controls please? Why VB2010 Express and not VS2015 community?

Comment: @Ben238 I find it simpler and faster. Picture coming soon.